# How to bind listview while ajaxcalling in webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string DeletePrescription(int PrescriptionId)
        {
            BusinessLogicLayer objBusiness = new BusinessLogicLayer();
            SanatanJeevanBusinessObjects.Prescription objPrescription = new SanatanJeevanBusinessObjects.Prescription();
            objPrescription.PrescriptionId = Convert.ToInt32(PrescriptionId);
            objBusiness.DeletePrescriptionBAL(objPrescription);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = objBusiness.GetPrescription(objPrescription);
            listPreDetails.DataSource = ds;
            listPreDetails.DataBind();
            return "success";
        }
```

hi, 
i am using ajax function to delete a row after delete the row in the table bind the data in listview. please help me.

Comment: You can't access controls inside static method.

Answer (score 0):

Although youll be deleting the item in the code behind it will still stay on the page because theres no way of interacting with your controls on the page

I have similar requirements but then remove the parent row from the screen using the JQuery below.

```
function Delete(idToDelete) {
var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
var id;

if (idToDelete.selector == undefined) {
    if (!$(this.id).selector == "") {
        id = $(this.id).selector;
    } else {
        id = idToDelete;
    }
} else {
    id = idToDelete;
}

  par.remove();
};
```

This works for me every time now.